# How to remove white space on several of urls

Tags: jquery, replace, slug

On a page with several urls I want to be able to remove the whitespace in the slug and replace it with a hyphen.
I can case where I have a single url, but I'm having trouble with multiple url case.
I assume the script must use `each(function())`
Based on the version I used for the single version I tried the following:

```
$(document).ready.(function() {
        $('a.testlink').each(function() {
            var Text = $(this);
            Text = Text.toLowerCase();
            Text = Text.replace(/[\s]+/g,'-');
            $(this).attr("href", Text);      
    });
         });
```

But the script fails completely having no effect on the url - it neither makes lower case nor replaces the whitespace.

How do I get the script to loop over each href and replace any spaces found in the slug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the line that says `var Text = $(this);` should be `var Text = $(this).attr("href");`